# What is the Z-transform of the sequence $-b^nu(1-n)$ and what is its ROC?

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

What is the Z-transform of the sequence $-b^nu(n-1)$ and what is its ROC?
Note: $u(n)$ is the unit step sequence.

My reasoning and possible solution is the following:

$$X(Z)= \sum_{k = - \infty}^{-1}(-b)^kz^{-k}=\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(-b)^{-k}z^k = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{-z}{b} \right )^k = -1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{-z}{b} \right )^k =-1 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{b}} = -1 + \frac{b}{z + b} = \frac{-z}{z+b}$$

Assuming that $\left | z \right | < \left | b \right |$ which would be the ROC.

Comment: You computed the Z-transform of the sequence $-b^{n} u(1 - n)$.  Was that what you wanted?

Comment: @fourierwho I'd like to know if the process and the results are correct. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the answer is yes if you wanted the Z-tranasform of $-b^{n} u(1 - n)$.  On the other hand, if you're really interested in $-b^{n} u(n - 1)$, then the sum should be from $k = 1$ to $k = \infty$.  Is that clear?

Comment: @fourierwho my mistake, I meant $−b^n u(1−n)$. On the other hand though, in the first step, shouldn't be only $b^k$ and not $(-b)^k$?

Comment: I agree.  Sorry, I missed that mistake before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(n) = -(b^n) u(1-n)$$

$$X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(n) z^{-n}$$

$$X(z) = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^{1}\frac{b^n}{z^n} $$

$$X(z) = - ( \frac{b}{z}+1+\frac{z}{b}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}+......)$$

Now apply the formula for sum of infinte GP

$$X(z) = -\frac{b}{b-z}$$

$$X(z) = \frac{b}{z-b}$$

$$|\frac{z}{b}|<1$$

$$ROC :|z|<|b|$$